# One-Hot Encoding without for-loop from vector of positions in Python with NumPy?

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn, one-hot-encoding

I have some data that I want to "one-hot encode" and it is represented as a 1-dimensional vector of positions.

**Is there any function in NumPy that can expand my `x` into my `x_ohe`?**

I'm trying to avoid using for-loops in Python at all costs for operations like this after watching [Jake Vanderplas's talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EEUXKG97YRw)

```
x = np.asarray([0,0,1,0,2])
x_ohe = np.zeros((len(x), 3), dtype=int)
for i, pos in enumerate(x):
    x_ohe[i,pos] = 1
x_ohe
# array([[1, 0, 0],
#        [1, 0, 0],
#        [0, 1, 0],
#        [1, 0, 0],
#        [0, 0, 1]])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `x` only contains non negative integers, you can compare `x` with a sequence use [*numpy broadcasting*](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.broadcasting.html) and convert the result to *int*s:

```
(x[:,None] == np.arange(x.max()+1)).astype(int)

#array([[1, 0, 0],
#       [1, 0, 0],
#       [0, 1, 0],
#       [1, 0, 0],
#       [0, 0, 1]])
```

---

Or initialize first, then assign ones use [*advanced indexing*](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing):

```
x_ohe = np.zeros((len(x), 3), dtype=int)
x_ohe[np.arange(len(x)), x] = 1
x_ohe

#array([[1, 0, 0],
#       [1, 0, 0],
#       [0, 1, 0],
#       [1, 0, 0],
#       [0, 0, 1]])
```

Answer (score 1):

A one liner :

```
np.equal.outer(x,range(3)).astype(int)

array([[1, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1]])
```

`np.equal.outer(x,np.unique(x)).astype(int)` works also here.